# Multiple CPU miners with low hashrate vs single CPU miner with high hashrate

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, algorithm

I looked at the [Monero algorythm](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt) (unfortunately not fully understood) and wonder if I could increase the probability of hitting a block with multiple CPU miners (low hashrate - for example 10 x 200h/s) or with a single CPU miner (high hashrate - for example 2000h/s).

Has anyone already drawn up a comparison and what strategy would make more sense with regard to the algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

If all the computers have a good network connectivity, the probability of successfully mining a block is proportional to your total hash rate.

Mining with 10 CPUs doing 200 h/s each and mining with 1 CPU doing 2000 h/s will give the same probability of finding a block.

Comment: So there is no lottery or something to increase the chance to "win" with more miners right? thx